# Finding the average of a column in a 2d array and putting the results in another matrix

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a method that figures out the average of the columns and then puts the answer in an other array. So I'm passing over 2 arrays and sending nothing. My issue here is that I get numbers that are way off. I know it's something small I'm over looking but please take a look at it:

```
public static void columnAverages(double [][] matrix1, double [][] matrix2)
{
    double sum; 
    for (int c = 1; c < matrix1[0].length; c++){
        sum = 0; 
        for (int r = 0; r < matrix1.length; r++){ 
            sum = sum + matrix1[r][c];
            matrix2[2][r]=sum/matrix1[0].length;
        }
    }
}
```

here are my very raw results

```
 Student   test1     test2     test3    average

  1.00     98.00     95.00     97.00     96.67
  2.00     97.00     96.00     96.00     96.33
  3.00     94.00     98.00     98.00     96.67

  0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
  0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
 19.33     38.60     57.93      0.00

 heres how I want the last table to look 
 lowest                    0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
 highest                   0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
 test averages go here     0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00(average of all the averages)
```

I am calling this method from main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("How many students are there?"); 
    int students=kb.nextInt(); 
    double [][] grades= new double [students][5]; 
    double [][] averages= new double [3][5]; 
    getScores(grades); 
    rowAverage(grades); 
    System.out.printf("%10s","Student"); 
    printArray(grades); 
    columnAverages(grades, averages); 
    System.out.println(); printArray(averages); 
    kb.close();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I've been stuck at this for such a long time.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling `columnAverages`? I just want to see what goes into the array. matrix1/matrix2 has no meaning to me!

Comment: this is my main method i tried putting it in code sorry if its confusing`public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many students are there?");
int students=kb.nextInt();
double [][] grades= new double [students][5];
double [][] averages= new double [3][5];

getScores(grades);
rowAverage(grades);
System.out.printf("%10s","Student");
printArray(grades);
columnAverages(grades, averages);
System.out.println();
printArray(averages);
kb.close();`

Comment: put the division into the outer for-loop

Comment: For starters, the student number should not be in the array.  There is no need. Second, why is `matrix2` columns shifted over with respect to `matrix1`? Lastly, why is there any data on your `matrix2` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
matrix2[2][r] = sum / matrix1[0].length;
```

It should be:

```
matrix2[2][c] = sum / matrix1.length;
```

**UPDATE:**
Don't forget to place the line outside the loop!